# Xamarin Formns: Multiple empty rows getting created after the data in list view

Tags: xamarin.forms

PFB the code for my list view,

```
 <ListView HasUnevenRows="true" ItemsSource="{Binding UserEmailList}" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" Style="{StaticResource labelHeaderTitle}" />
                                <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" >
                              <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding UserEmailDetails.HasEmailAddress}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding UserEmailDetails.EmailAddress}" Style="{StaticResource labelListItem}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SelectEmailAddress_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding UserEmailDetails}" />
                                  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                                <Image HeightRequest="16" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="arrow.png" Margin="0,0,15,0">
                                </Image>
                              </StackLayout>
                              <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding UserEmailDetails.HasEmailAddress, Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}" Padding="15,0,0,0">
                                <Label Text="Add email" Style="{StaticResource labelLink}">
                                  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SelectEmailAddress_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding UserEmailDetails}" />
                                  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                              </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Even if there are only two rows, on IOS multiple empty rows are getting populated as in the below snapshot.

Please let me know how to avoid this and hav things working in both Android and IOS

[image]

Comment: AFAIK this is normal behavior on iOS.  For example, if you search in the default Mail app and return less than a full page of hits, the remaining rows will show as blank cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hide the Separator by setting SeparatorVisibility="None" on ListView Property. If you still need the Separator I would define in the ViewCell.

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorVisibility="None">
```

The other way is to put Empty Footer on List View:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <Label />
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

I hope one of these helps you. Let me know if anything.